# NoMethodError in RevisionsController#new /undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a WIKI page using rails 3. I am following a tutorial by http://garrickvanburen.com/archive/how-to-build-a-wiki-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1/

I believe his tutorial is in rails 2 so i am having to change the coding around. I am on section 6 and have inputed the coding inside app/views/revisions/new.html.erb.Once I load the server in  localhost/revisions/new i get the following error-

NoMethodError in RevisionsController#new

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: /home/whitey7/wiki
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/revisions_controller.rb:30:in `new'

when I pull up the revisions_controller file and view line 30 it seems correct or correct according to what was in the tutorial. Everything else seems to work fine but this. I can't seem to find the answer or how to fix this. Any help or some guidance would be greatly appreciated. The code is below thats listed in the revisions_controller file.  Thanks all!!

```
  # GET /revisions/new
  # GET /revisions/new.json


def new
    @revision = Revision.new

    @revision.update_attribute('person_id', 
      Person.find_or_create_by_name(params[:person][:name]).id) **#Inputed from Tutorial.**

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @revision }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Are you referring to something like this? people.create(params[:person]) underneath Person.find_or_create_by_name(params[:person][:name]).id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

params[:person] isn't set. If you just want to avoid the error in this case, change to:

```
unless params[:person].nil?
  @revision.update_attribute('person_id', 
    Person.find_or_create_by_name(params[:person][:name]).id)
end
```

Comment: I added params[:person] to the below Revision.new but it doesn't seem right or like im in the right spot to set it.

Comment: Do you by chance know were is the correct place to set params[:persons] in the code is? thanks for the above response I will try that if I can't figure it out.

Comment: params[:person] doesn't get set in your code. If you're familiar with PHP, it's the equivalent of $_POST['person']. In get requests, params are defined by the url based on your routes.rb file. In post requests, it's from input tags on the page. As for what the tutorial is trying to do, I have no idea. It shouldn't ever be set in your new method.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will dig around and see what I can find out.